# Could not load file or assembly MVC in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, azure

I have this exception (see bottom) and have no clue what to do. I tried to deploy my website on Azure websites. Locally everything works fine. This was the first time I tried to deploy it, so I had no previous working version online.
I used NU-Get to install ASP.Net MVC. The properties are set to `CopyLocal = True`.
My target framework is set to `.NET 4.5` (also configured in Azure portal). There is not any intelligence going on in my project, just a home controller and a view. 
I have this in my web.config:

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The only other package I installed is jquery.
Other, probably irrelevant detail: I have a test-project, which was untouched after creating the project from scratch.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Stack Trace:

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   EchteMaaltijd.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\a\src\EchteMaaltijd\EchteMaaltijd\Global.asax.cs:16

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext context, HttpApplication app) +12600621
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +175
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12617668
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12457285
```

Comment: Ok, "semi-solved this", the bin was not installed in azure. I tried to deploy using continuous delivery with Visual Studio Online.
This did not deploy the bin files. When I used publish to deploy to Azure, it did install the bin files correctly.

I still don't know why this wouldn't work using continuous delivery, but at least I can deploy now.